# How to compare right skewed data with non-parametric test?! Which test is the right one

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric, skewness

I am trying to compare cell sizes from multiple locations. I have 5 biopsy locations from 25 individuals = 125 single tissue biopsies.
The cell size is acquired using digital image processing and one cell = one count and one area - so one tissue biopsy A may have a cell count of 160 giving 160 cell areas for this biopsy, where another biopsy B may have a cell count of 550 giving 550 cell areas. So a mean from A builds on fewer observations than a mean from B.

The data is right skewed and can't be transformed.

So, I want to compare the cell sizes from the different locations - do I use the Mann-Whitney for unpaired data?

or is my data paired because of the biopsies arising from the same individuals, meaning I should use Wilcoxon but this test assumes that I have the same amount of observations pr locations, which I don't.

Comment: "can't be transformed": why not? The first thing to do with data on areas is to see whether they behave more simply on logarithmic scale.  It's worth mentioning also that square root scale might appeal as simple dimensionally, given that the square root of an area is length.

Answer (score 1):

If you are taking 5 measurements from the same individual but at different locations then this is not paired data. So you are trying to compare means from 5 different biopsy locations, 5 different measurements from each individual, 25 individuals total, with unequal biopsy sample sizes and right skewed data?

The test you will use depends on your objective: do you want to determine if there is a difference in means in any of the 5 locations? If so -> ANOVA. If you want to test each pair of means -> Tukey HSD test.

Note: both ANOVA and Tukey (which are based on F-tests and t-tests) make no assumptions on the distribution of the data. The assumption is on the residuals which are supposed to be normal, so just because you have skewed data does not mean these methods are out (same is true for F and t tests).

Note 2: both ANOVA and Tukey also assume homogeneity of variance, that is equal variance in all groups; if that is not true -> non-parametric tests.

If the residuals are not normal or variances are not equal then you can use a non-parametric test as you already mentioned. However, keep in mind that if you are going to use univariate methods such as t-tests or Mann Whitney tests you will have to adjust your p-values.

Comment: Are you saying that two measurements from the same person are generally not more similar that two measurements from two different subjects? If so, how can that be? If not, what _are_ you saying in your first paragraph?

Comment: @BruceET I am saying that the 5 measurements taken from the same individual at different locations are not paired, so we are not using a paired test. So we treat these measurements as coming from different distributions, since the OP did not mention that they are related.

Comment: Thanks!! Yes, unequal sample size and rigth skewed data. 

The 5 different locations are the same locations from each individual. The locations are the impotant factor in our analysis - we want to se if there is a difference in cell size between the 5 different locations. 

Some researcher have said that the mean does not describe data which does not fit a normal distribution in the optimum manner. That's why I got a bit confused because a lot af tests compare the means.

Comment: @ISAK In the end it depends on your objective, if you think the mean is not a good estimate for your objective (for ex. because the data is too skewed), then you can use a non-parametric version of ANOVA or Tukey, which won't compare means but some other property such as distribution.